# Flutter firebase messaging iOS provisioning profile

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a question regarding the iOS setup of firebase messaging with flutter.

On the provisioning profile section in the documentation

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#3-generating-a-provisioning-profile

There is this section

```
On the "Profiles" menu item, register a new Profile. Select the "iOS App Development" (or macOS) checkbox and click "Continue".
```

Now I have done this and my notifications are working fine on my device. However I noticed another type on the page when i was setting up the provisioning profile that was labelled "Distribution->App Store".

I also noticed that the "iOS App Development" was also labelled with "Create a provisioning profile to install development apps on test devices." -> The test devices section concerns me a bit.

[image: App developer page]

Do we actually have to make another provisioning profile using this "Distribution->App Store" type if we plan on releasing on the app store?

If so how do add it to my app instead of the development one

Comment: "Create a provisioning profile to install development apps on test devices" => You can test your app on your device.  If you add device UDIDs to the list, you can even distributed the IPA of your app to device owners.

Comment: "Distribution->App Store" type if we plan on releasing on the app store? - Yes, XCode does it for u automatically if it does not, it's just at the signing session, u have a config to development and another for distribution (or release, I dont remember)

Comment: So are you saying i need to make another profile for distribution (or release)